# is it possible to change the name of an iOS app via xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes-store

we want to publish an update of our app. Is it possible to rename the app after the update? let's say the app is called **myApp** and I want it to be called **myApp 2** after the update... can it be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Actually you can. You can change the "Bundle Name" which (I think) is the name the App appears on the AppStore and the "Bundle Display Name" which is the name that appears under your icon on the Home screen. But if you change your "Bundle Identifier" then your App is not the same App.
More info can be found [in the Apple Docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-110725).

Answer (score 46):

*In Build Setting*, You can change **Product Name**.

[image]

Comment: This is great! Without changing the project and directory name. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By far the easiest best method, the picture did the explaining.

Answer (score 9):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074959/480415

> select your target, "Info" tab, and set the "Bundle display name"
>   field to the name you want (i.e. "MySuperApp"). This is the simplest,
>   pain-free solution.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, you need to modify `Bundle display name` in your .plist file

Answer (score 4):

Actually there are several "app names"... 
(such as several people call you "friend", "John", "father", "son",... hehehe!)

**1) the name that you see below the icon** - you can change in several ways, but the best suggestion is from @gWiz, just change your "Bundle display name" in your Target properties (tab "Info", or you can find it called "Display Name" in the tab "General").

*Bundle display name: (Required, Localizable) The user-visible name of the bundle; used by Siri and visible on the Home screen in iOS. See CFBundleDisplayName for details.*

**2) the Bundle Name**, found in the same "Info" tab, is not "*the name the App appears on the AppStore*" as suggested by @gWiz, rather:

*Bundle Name: (Recommended, Localizable) The short name of the bundle; **not intended to be seen by the user**. See CFBundleName for details.*

**3) another name is the Product Name**, that you can find in "Build Setting" tab - @Lihn suggestion is okay, as from Apple documentation "*The product name is the name of your app as it will appear to customers in the store and should be similar to the app name you enter later in iTunes Connect.*"... but this is a bit confusing, and not 100% correct. In iOS the "Product Name" is not used too much, just forget it. In MacOS maybe you can see somewhere... (suggestions?)

**4) the name that you see in AppStore**, this is asked in [iTunesConnect](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/CreatingiTunesConnectRecord.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13) when you create a new app (or want to modify metadata with a new binary version), and is usually just called "Name", or "App Name" in Apple documentation...

*App Name: (Required, Localizable) The name of the app as shown in AppStore.*

**5)** Name of the schemes, name of the targets,... probably you're not interested, or you can experiment by yourself, or read Apple docs (better to experiment, for me)

---

At the moment I cannot give you more details, as:

[image]

but the main idea is:

- The **name below the icon**, on the device, can be edited at a new binary submission changing "Bundle display name"
- The **name of the app**, as seen inside the AppStore, can be edited again every new binary submission, changing "Name" or "App Name" directly in iTunes.

...and both are localizable.

Answer (score 2):

The app name is the Product name for Debug/Release in Build Settings -> Packaging.
If you change it then the Bundle name and Bundle display name might change too if the default ${PRODUCT_NAME} value is there. 
According to the Apple docs Bundle Display Name is the name that is displayed under the app icon while Bundle Name is a short name of the above but I am unaware of anything that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

just double click on your project name and rename it, then it will ask for changing all references in project click change.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the apps name see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1625/_index.html

However, the directory for the app's data will change as well. If you want to move some data, you can find the directory used by the simulator e.g. with:
    NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory(); NSLog(@"%@",homeDir);
before and after renaming and use 'Go to Folder' in finder to get there.