# 'warning: directory not found for option' error on build

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

All of a sudden my app has started giving me an error when I try to build it. This is the error I'm getting:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Documents/Developer/Alton-Towers-Times/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mouse_Times_Florida-eqhrhnbxmmkxtahdghmnvehbzbgt/Build/Intermediates/Mouse Times Florida.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mouse Times Florida WatchKit Extension.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SecondInterfaceController.o' for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Only thing I've really done since I last managed to get it to run was changing the bundle IDs and I also changed the app name. I've tried a few things including deleting the derived data, but nothing seems to have helped.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are there both `Mouse_Times_Florida` and `Alton-Towers-Times` in the log? Perhaps you changed the project name and some build settings are out of date?

Comment: Yeah, I changed the project name but I'm not sure what build settings I should be changing?

Comment: You can do a project-wide search for the old name to find if there's anything left over.

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594231/is-it-possible-to-change-the-name-of-an-ios-app-via-xcode

Answer (score 8):

I solved this warning removing the following setting: "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

This options is located in Settings -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Framework Search Paths

[Setting location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6OqQ.png)

My project continues compiling and working fine, after removing this option.

Comment: this solution caused more problems

Answer (score 5):

Veladan answer helped me to sort out that issue on an iOS8 project freshly migrated to iOS9.
This worked fine on the main target of my project, but the warning lasted on the unit tests target, so in the end I edited directly the project.pbxproj file and modified the entries :

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
    "$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks",
    "$(inherited)",
);
```

to :

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = "";
```