# directory not found for option .../Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf': error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c

```
Ld /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.app/ABA normal i386
    cd "/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project with pod"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod -L/Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf -F/Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod/Pods/FirebaseCrash/Frameworks -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/MAC-mini/Documents/Kalpesh/ABA/Project\ with\ pod/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Frameworks -filelist /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ABA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.build/Objects-normal/i386/ABA.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ABA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.build/Objects-normal/i386/ABA_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework CoreTelephony -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCrash -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ABA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.build/ABA.app.xcent -framework UserNotifications -framework CoreTelephony -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -lxml2 -framework Pushbots -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework Security -framework CoreData -lsqlite3.0 -lz.1.2.5 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -lPods-ABA -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ABA.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.build/Objects-normal/i386/ABA_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ABA.app/ABA

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/MAC-mini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
ld: library not found for -lPods-ABA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please see: [ask].

Comment: This Error appear on only when try to run on simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link - ['warning: directory not found for option' error on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040038/warning-directory-not-found-for-option-error-on-build)

Comment: If you are trying run firebase code on simulator then this you can not run firebase code on simulator. You must have a device for it.